# Change background color of ListView position wise

Tags: java, android

I am new to android.In one of my project I am using list view and in an adapter, I am going to change the background color.

when I am using this code its working fine.

```
if (position % 2 == 0) {
    rowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
} else {
    rowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
}
```

but, when I am going to change condition like this.its not working why?

```
if (position % 2 != 0) {    
    rowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
}
```

Comment: What is the issue showing?

Comment: Well, you've reversed the color logic, but are sure that `R.color.red` has been defined in your project?

Comment: you are not just changing the condition.... you are changing the parameter by ***Color.RED***

Comment: yes r.color.red .defined.....issue is .......when i am scrolling list view all view is going to change in red.

Comment: replace listview with recyclerview.

Comment: i know that recycle view works on unique id or position......but i want to know what is wrong with this condition....why its not working?

Comment: @SibinDavis can u tell me what is happening in this condition?

Comment: It is a bug with listview.

Comment: @SibinDavis can u please explain it to me so i can understand it?

Comment: Are'nt you adding the else clause???

Comment: why? because you are not setting the background to white color anymore, just use `rowView.setBackgroundColor(position % 2 != 0? Color.RED : Color.WHITE);`

Comment: @SaiJayant i dont want to use else clause....is that make the difference?

Comment: Sometimes it causes

Comment: try it and tell me

Comment: @pskink you are giving me another solutions .....but i want to know what is wrong with is code .

Comment: @SaiJayant i have already try with else clause and its working fine.....but i want to know what is wrong with second code?

Comment: i already told you: `because you are not setting the background to white color anymore`

Comment: @pskink i don't want to set white color ...thats why i try to change condition.....so what happen if i don't set white color?

Comment: what happens? the old color is used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListView cells are reused. When you're filling a cell you start with a previously used cell which may already have red or white background color. And if you don't change that color the previous setting remains and is displayed to user. So as the rule of thumb you must always setup every subview when you're filling a ListView/RecyclerView cell.

Answer (score 0):

> An if statement can be followed by an optional else statement, which
>   executes when the Boolean expression is false.
>   The **ELSE** statement effectively says that whatever code after it 
>   is executed if the if statement is **FALSE** .

- Add **ELSE** Statement for good practice .

Comment: i have tried its not working still got all view as red after scrolling up and down.

Comment: @umeshvashisth why dont you simply call `setBackground Color` unconditionally? like: `rowView.setBackgroundColor(position % 2 != 0? Color.RED : Color.WHITE);`

Comment: @pskink i appreciate your ans but i want to know why its not working if i dont set white color or else part...i know that ternary will work and already tried it.....just want to know(logic ) behind it.

Comment: @pskink ok...can you please explain how this will happen ...that old ones are used again ????

Comment: @umeshvashisth see http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterperformance_convertview

Comment: @umeshvashisth Buddy Easily understand, it is issue with ListView. Whenever you want to use listview and would like to `setBackGround..` or `setChecked..`, you have to use `if`...`else` condition. That will work properly.

Comment: @umeshvashisth Glad to hear . FYI #pskink is not buddy . He is sir.